# Why was my question closed as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Here is the question I asked: [How to capture a single class data member in a lambda expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653624/how-to-capture-a-single-class-data-member-in-a-lambda-expression). However I don't understand why it was marked as a duplicate of [C++11 lambdas: member variable capture gotcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764564/c11-lambdas-member-variable-capture-gotcha).

I understand the other question but I fail to see how it serves as an answer to my question.

Can someone please enlighten me or perhaps confirm my suspicion that it was closed incorrectly?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the answer to the dupe target is the answer to your question:

> Yes. Capturing member variables is always done via capturing this; it
>   is the only way to access a member variable.

The questions have the same answer, so an answer saying:

> No, you can't, see this other question

Isn't useful, and it was closed as a dupe of that question.

**Update:**

It appears that the correct answer has changed since the duplicate was posted. In some ways, it's still a duplicate because the other answer could/should be updated to include this information. That said, due to your questions more specific scope, I have voted to reopen.

Comment: I understand that logic but my question is about capturing a single member via this instead of all of them. Furthermore, from the answers I received it appears the answer ***Yes, it's possible but you need C++14 features***. So isn't that a different and valid answer?

Comment: @JamesAdkison If I had noticed that, I would agree :). I can see why the original dupe flags were cast if they weren't carefully reading the existing answers though.

Comment: This is new territory for me. So should I make an edit to my question stating why I think it's different than the other question?

Comment: @JamesAdkison Yes, making a comment/edit noting that the answer can/is different than the dupe due to the scope would be appropriate. Just keep it civil :)

Comment: [Kate Gregory outlines the correct procedure](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194479/) on Meta.SE, @JamesAdkison.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thanks for the link. That makes a lot of sense and makes the question much less awkward (especially in the event it gets reopened). I'll update my question in this manner.